# iPhone - HTTPS connection to Server with Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: iphone, certificate, self, signed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use NSURLCredentialStorage for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501231/can-i-use-nsurlcredentialstorage-for-http-basic-authentication)

How would I accept a self-signed server certificate? Using the code below, I can only connect/authenticate after I accept the Server Cert using Safari.

```
- (void)secure:(NSString *)username credentials:(NSString *)login
{
  NSURLCredential *userCredentials = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                                password:login
                                                             persistence:
                                                        NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

  NSURLProtectionSpace *space = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:LIST_URL_HTTPS
                                                                      port:443
                                                                   protocol:@"https"
                                                                     realm:@"Restricted Area"
                                                      authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

  [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setCredential:userCredentials
                                               forProtectionSpace:space];


  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed
                                                        timeoutInterval:30];

  NSURLResponse *response;
  NSError *error;

  NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                             returningResponse:&response
                                                         error:&error];

}
```