# nsurlconnection synchronize

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I used synchronize method of nsurlconnection for initiating the network connection. Since my system is behind a proxy i want to add the code for challenge response. The problem which i am facing is that the challenge response method is not getting called. is using synchronize method is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` by "synchronize`?

If so, `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` is not called for synchronous requests. But you can still provide `NSURLCredential` / `NSURLProtectionSpace` and store it into `NSURLCredentialStorage` before sending the request.

Check Mike's answer here: [Can I use NSURLCredentialStorage for HTTP Basic Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501231/can-i-use-nsurlcredentialstorage-for-http-basic-authentication)