# Making a login system for a Mac app

Tags: objective-c, curl

I am currently working on an app that uses basic Auth. and logs in with an API which is written in CURL, so what would be the easiest way about doing this? NSURL or Libcurl? and how would i do it?

Is there any example of what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use the [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, since it comes nicely packaged in Cocoa.  Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501231/can-i-use-nsurlcredentialstorage-for-http-basic-authentication) for a good example of how to properly use it for basic authentication.  Hopefully that gives you an idea how to authenticate using the Cocoa framework.