# NSURLConnection doesn't call NSURLConnectionDelegate authentication methods after an HTTP 401

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, http-authentication, nsurlconnectiondelegate, nsurlcredential

I'm consume a web service that uses HTTP basic auth with an `NSURLConnection`. In my `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, I implemented `–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:]`,
`–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:]`, and
`–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:]`, but none of them get called.

I've tried implementing `–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:]` to return both `YES` and `NO`, but that had no effect.

[I also ensured that my `NSURLCredentialStorage` was empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536425/9636).

Finally, instead of implementing `–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:]`,
`–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:]`, and
`–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:]`, I implemented `–[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:]`, but it wasn't called either.

What can I do to make `NSURLConnection` call `NSURLConnectionDelegate`'s authentication callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My HTTP server isn't returning a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

My server's response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 14:43:30 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Expires: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 14:43:30 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Another server response with a `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 14:44:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="[LDAP/PROD] Active Directory"
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

It looks like `NSURLConnection` requires the `WWW-Authenticate` header in its response for it to call `NSURLConnectionDelegate`'s authentication callbacks.

I've [filed a radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/14203257) about this. Please duplicate it.

Apparently, I'll have to manually set the `Authorization` header since [`NSURLConnection` will not allow you to proactively authenticate with `NSURLCredential`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379258/nsurlconnection-does-not-use-the-default-credential).